# How to read another cell from within a UDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I am aware that it's very hard to change the value of another cell using a User Defined Function - forbbiden by MS, even. However, I'd like to **just read** from another cell and do something with that information, but the function never runs thoroughly. For instance, in

```
Public Function ADD(arg1 as Double, arg2 as Double) as Double

    If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value = 0 Then
        ADD = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    MsgBox "I got here"

    ADD = arg1 + arg2

End Function
```

the message box does not show up. It can only be the if-statement. When I remove it, it works. **Is there any way to read from another fixed cell without crashing the function?** The real function I'm working with does all the reading from within if-statements.

Also, this can be found on the MS website, but I don't understand why it prevents me from reading..

> For correct calculation, all ranges that are used in the calculation should be passed to the function as arguments. If you do not pass the calculation ranges as arguments, instead of referring to the ranges within the VBA code of the function, Excel cannot account for them within the calculation engine. Therefore, Excel may not adequately calculate the workbook to make sure that all precedents are calculated before calculating the user-defined function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it works for me, but the value does not change when only A1 is changed.  Like the info says it does not know that the value changed.  If you make it volatile will, but It would be better to pass that range reference as an argument.

Comment: The default value of an empty cell is zero, so if you have that cell empty and you're expecting your If test to fail, it won't.  Put some other value in A1.  You will at least need `Application.Volatile` as the first line in your function if you expect it to recalculate when you change the value of A1 (even then it's likely not guaranteed)

Comment: I'm going to improve the question soon. I thank you for the suggestions. I'm pretty sure they didn't work because my example didn't capture the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the UDF name to `ADDD()` and it works fine:

```
Public Function ADDD(arg1 As Double, arg2 As Double) As Double

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = 0 Then
        ADDD = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    MsgBox "I got here"

    ADDD = arg1 + arg2

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It did solve the example but did not change anything for the real thing, which means my example was flawed. I'm going to edit the question later doing a better job.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot run a message box with a UDF**. Can you image how many times you would have to click "OK" if you could and your sheet recalculated frequently?

Instead, you can use a `debug.print` statement, and you can run your UDF from the VBA IDE to check the debug values. For example:

```
Private Function TestMyUDF()
Dim examplevalue1 as Double
Dim examplevalue2 as Double
    MyUDF examplevalue1, examplevalue2
End Function
```

Off-question, but if your referenced (read-only) cell is significant, then use a named range (and make it a workbook name, not a sheet one). Let us call it "CheckSumCell" for the sake of an example.

```
Public Function MyUDF(arg1 as Double, arg2 as Double) as Double
    If ThisWorkbook.Names("CheckSumCell").Value = 0 Then '<-- assumes single cell
        MyUDF = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    MyUDF= arg1 + arg2
End Function
```

This will then better survive cell relocation (insertion of rows or columns)! If you decide to use another cell, then just change the definition of the named range and you will not require to edit the macro/UDF at all.